# asp mvc custom view location

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, razorengine

I have configured my controller to return a view from a custom location rather than the typical Views folder. This has been achieved by adding the following code to Global.asax

```
 var razorEngine = ViewEngines.Engines.OfType<RazorViewEngine>().First();
        razorEngine.ViewLocationFormats = razorEngine.ViewLocationFormats.Concat(new string[]
        {
            "~/UI/app/{1}/Views/{0}.cshtml"
        }).ToArray();
```

It is working fine but i am facing issues with linking css, images and js files to the cshtml page. When loading the page, seems like those files are 404 not found and on the console i receive "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)".

Not sure if I am missing something or why it is unable to find the path to my content files.
The way i referenced the content files were as follows: ~/path to the location

Comment: CSS and JS files use bundling & optimization mechanism - check the layout view which contains `Styles/Scripts` rendering. Include `Application_Start` method & `BundleConfig` code for clarity finding out exact problem.

Comment: What is the actual path to your content files?

Comment: @garethb path to content is ~/UI/app/Home/JS and the view lives just on Home/Views

Comment: Pretty sure .net will block any requests from view folders (thats why you're getting 404's). I can't remember but there were some pretty good reasons for this. Google it? There are ways around allowing it in your config, but general recommendations are to keep you js files in the default scripts folder.

Comment: Managed to solve the issue. Added a web config file to the custom directory and made sure to update path from "*" to "*.cshtml" on BlockViewHandler

Answer (score 0):

Solved the issue by adding web config to the custom directory and making sure the BlockViewHandler path was set to "*.cshtml".
e.g. From

```
<add name="BlockViewHandler" path="*" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.HttpNotFoundHandler" />
```

To

```
<add name="BlockViewHandler" path="*.cshtml" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.HttpNotFoundHandler" />
```

Hope it helps others :)